# OSWorklow integration with spring

Tags: java, spring, wicket, integration, osworkflow

I am facing issue while adding the bean id named `SessionFactory` while configuring osworkflow-spring.xml file. What i understood from the issue is mismatch between spring and hibernate dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.Beta2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

after reading some documentation is suggests to add only spring and hibernate which i guess i did. It still giving me error on adding few more classes.. So i am totally confused.
Any help is appreciated.
Regards.